# NullReferenceException when accessing variables in a 2D array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

I have made a class including variables in Monodevelop which is:

```
public class GridInfo : MonoBehaviour {

    public float initPosX;
    public float initPosY;
    public bool inUse;
    public int f;
    public int g;
    public int h;
    public GridInfo parent;
    public int  y,x;        
}
```

Now I am using its class variable in another class, Map.cs which is:

```
public class Map : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GridInfo[,] Tile = new GridInfo[17, 23];

    void Start() {

        Tile[0,0].initPosX = initPosX;  //Line 49
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error on runtime, but when I play in unity it is giving me error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Map.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Map.cs:49)
```

I am not inserting this script in any gameobject, as Map.cs will make a GridInfo type array, I have also tried using variables using GetComponent, where is the problem ?

Comment: `I am not getting any error on runtime, but when I play in unity it is giving me error ` What do you mean by that? Is that not at runtime?

Comment: Please add more code, at least everything that is referenced in the snippet, like `initPosX`` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont understand Unity and MonoDevelop, bud I think, you don't have objects in array intialized. You created array, but objects in it are null. You have to call new GridInfo on each of them.

Somethink like:

```
foreach (GridInfo gi in Tile) // I now don't know, if this goes over 2D array too
{
   gi = new Grid();
}
```

Comment: hey thnx..it wrking nw..

Comment: To be precise, `foreach` won't work in this case because C# doesn't allow assignments to the iteration variable. A `for( ; ; )` loop or other means is needed instead.

Answer (score 0):

To give an alternative to zacharmarz's answer:

The way that I think you intend to use the `GridInfo` is possible, if you change it to a `struct` instead of a `class`. If you do, then you can't inherit from MonoBehaviour, but I think that you might do that unintentionally because Unity automatically inserts that code when creating the script.
Since the GridInfo is just a *structure* of multiple public data fields, it is well suited for using a struct.

Note that I'm not sure if it is possible to have a struct of the same type inside the struct, as in the case of the field `parent`.

It would look like this:

```
public struct GridInfo {
    public float initPosX;
    public float initPosY;
    public bool inUse;
    public int f;
    public int g;
    public int h;
    public GridInfo parent;
    public int y,x;        
}
```

Then a 2D-array of structs will automatically contain the structs with all their fields. There are no nullpointers of type struct.